# os.walk multiple directories at once

Tags: python, os.walk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to join two generators in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211041/how-to-join-two-generators-in-python)

Is there a way in python to use os.walk to traverse multiple directories at once?

```
my_paths = []
path1 = '/path/to/directory/one/'
path2 = '/path/to/directory/two/'
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(path1, path2):
    my_paths.append(dirs)
```

The above example doesn't work (as os.walk only accepts one directory), but I was hoping for a more elegant solution rather than calling os.walk twice (plus then I can sort it all at once). Thanks.

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/q/3211041/320726 ?

Comment: @6502 nice catch; it's an exact duplicate.

Comment: And quite appropriate, as we now have three identical answers as well as it being an identical question.

Comment: Exact duplicate question with exact duplicate answers! Nice!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I was first by 90 seconds :P

Comment: @agf Actually, Phillip beat you by 14 months!!  ;-)

Comment: Apologies for not seeing that.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To treat multiples iterables as one, use [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

paths = ('/path/to/directory/one/', '/path/to/directory/two/', 'etc.', 'etc.')
for path, dirs, files in chain.from_iterable(os.walk(path) for path in paths):
```

Comment: Thanks, amazing!

Answer (score 7):

Use [`itertools.chain()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

```
for path, dirs, files in itertools.chain(os.walk(path1), os.walk(path2)):
    my_paths.append(dirs)
```

Answer (score 5):

Others have mentioned `itertools.chain`.

There's also the option of just nesting one level more:

```
my_paths = []
for p in ['/path/to/directory/one/', '/path/to/directory/two/']:
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(p):
        my_paths.append(dirs)
```

Comment: I had thought about doing it that way, but I figured there was a more "pythonic" way of doing it. Thanks!

Comment: I like this solution since it does not require a special lib.

Comment: For my use case this is perfectly simple, thanks.

Comment: The chain solution is work but personally I like this one. Less import.

Answer (score 1):

since nobody mentioned it, in this or the other referenced post:

http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Pool
>>> p = Pool(5)
>>> def f(x):
...     return x*x
...
>>> p.map(f, [1,2,3])
```

in this case, you'd have a list of directories.  the call to map would return a list of lists from each dir, you could then choose to flatten it, or keep your results clustered

```
def t(p):
    my_paths = []
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(p):
        my_paths.append(dirs)


paths = ['p1','p2','etc']
p = Pool(len(paths))
dirs = p.map(t,paths)
```

Comment: He doesn't mean "at once" as in "at the same time" but as in "as a set" or "as a unit", so your answer doesn't really address his question.

Comment: I believe it does both right?  Not only do you get back your search along multiple paths as a list, which is what everyone's chain() suggestion does, but this has the added benefit of doing all these searches as a separate process. What if these are paths do unique drives. If that's the case you get even better results using this method since you are searching multiple drives simultaneously.