# Merge iterables of Validationerror into one single iterable of Validationerror in JSON Schema

Tags: json, python-2.7, generator, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

In `jsonschema` validation, I am looking to print all the `Validationerror` of several `instances` with several respective `schemas` in one single `for` loop as opposed to one `for` loop for one round of validation. I want to do something like this:

```
validator = jsonschema.Draft4Validator(schema1)
errors1 = validator.iter_errors(instance1)
validator = jsonschema.Draft4Validator(schema2)
errors2 = validator.iter_errors(instance2)
for error in errors1 + errors2:
    print error.message
```

But, I can't do `errors1 + errors2` as they are of type `generator`.  Is there a way to add all the errors into one single iterable so I can use just one `for` loop? Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar question is here [How to join two generators in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211041/how-to-join-two-generators-in-python)

You have to use `itertools.chain()` function to join generators

```
for error in itertools.chain(errors1, errors2):
    print error.message
```